# What is the difference between Hall Effect and Magnetoresistance?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I was learning about sensors. I was confused about the Hall Sensors and Magnetoresistive Sensors. They both seem to be same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Magnetoresistive effect:**
As the name 'magneto**resistive**' says, the resistance of a special material is changed by a magnetic field.

**Hall-effect:**
In Hall-effect, however, a voltage is generated perpendictular to the direction of current flow and direction of magnetic field. No change of resistance happens here.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance) on magnetoresistance (in the footnote): -

> The (ordinary) Hall effect changes sign upon magnetic field reversal
>   and it is an orbital effect (unrelated to spin) due to the Lorentz
>   force. Transversal AMR (planar Hall effect) does not change sign
>   and it is caused by spin-orbit interaction.

Magnetoresistance falls into the AMR area of things (as mentioned early on in the wiki article) so you could argue it is similar to what is found in ordinary Hall effect sensors but the two things are still different.